# Control one iFrame from another iFrame

Tags: iframe, target

This works …

```
<a href="page.html" target="frameName">Link text</a>
```

but this doesn't …

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var a = document.getElementById("mylink");
      a.onclick = function() {
        parent.document.getElementById('frameName').src = 'page.html';
      }
    }
</script>

<a id="mylink" href="page.html">LINK</a>
```

Any idea why I can't get the element by id from one iFrame to another? Also I know very little code so I apologize in advance if its obvious.

Comment: What browsers have you tried this in? I think it's probably a security measure.

Answer (score 0):

First i would make sure that the security of the site within the IFrame allows you to do this kind of stuff. Check out this link:
[Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

Next, i would worry about the target of your anchor tag. With specifying it will default to self. In your second piece of code the target will be _self. Thus, when you click the link your javascript will want to change the source of the IFrame while the link will want to change the entire page. I would pick either a JS or HTML implemetation of linking and not both. Here is something that i put together to show one way of changing the iFrame without an actual anchor tag.

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="frameName" src="page.html"></iframe>
<button onclick="changeFrame()">LINK</button>
<script>
    function changeFrame() {
          document.getElementById('frameName').src ='page2.html';
      }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```